# Trying to get Callout to work with EventSeries and DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling, date-and-time, time-series

I can get ListPlot to work with Callout. Here is toy code:

```
data = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7};
val1L = ReplacePart[data, 9 -> Callout[0, "First Period End", {10, 1}]]
ListPlot[val1L, Joined -> True]
```

Producing:

[image]

If I create an EventSeries, and then rescale this to have a range of dates, like so:

```
es = EventSeries[val1L, Automatic]
rescaleTS = 
  Table[
    {DatePlus[
       DateObject["January 1, 2020"], {i - 1, "Month"}], 
       Normal[es][[i]][[2]]}, 
    {i, 1, es["PathLength"]}]
```

The first part of the output looks like this:

[image]

When I plot this with DateListPlot it seems to ignore the Callout wrapper, producing:

[image]

For completeness the DateListPlot command is just:

```
DateListPlot[rescaleES]
```

Comment: You can use `Epilog`, e.g., `DateListPlot[rescaleTS, Epilog -> {Text["First Period End", {{2020, 9, 1}, 0}, {-1.25, -1.25}]}]`

Answer (score 4):

You did not form the callout properly. Here is a way that works.

```
data = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7};
es = EventSeries[data, Automatic];
rescaleTS = 
  Table[
    {DatePlus[
       DateObject["January 1, 2020"], {i - 1, "Month"}], 
       Normal[es][[i]][[2]]}, 
    {i, 1, es["PathLength"]}];
vals = ReplacePart[rescaleTS, 9 -> Callout[rescaleTS[[9]], "First Period End"]];
DateListPlot[vals]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

However, if you were intended to label both period endings, I would recommend:

```
data = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7};
es = EventSeries[data, Automatic];
rescaleTS = 
  Table[
    {DatePlus[
       DateObject["January 1, 2020"], {i - 1, "Month"}], 
       Normal[es][[i]][[2]]}, 
    {i, 1, es["PathLength"]}];
rescaleTS[[9]] = Callout[rescaleTS[[9]], "1st Period End", After];
rescaleTS[[15]] = Callout[rescaleTS[[15]], "2nd Period End", After];
DateListPlot[rescaleTS]
```

[image: plot]

And, actually, this approach might be better even if you only wanted one callout.